# Unabale to delete .Trash-0 folder

Tags: command-line, permanent-delete

I tried:

```
# rm -r .Trash-0
# rm -rf .Trash-0
```

But of no use. This file doesn't get deleted. It says "read only file system cannot be deleted".

Comment: refer [here](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1282123)

Comment: Not working!! I tried to change the permission, but no use

Answer (score 0):

Boot from ubuntu install media - choose 'Try Ubuntu'.

Mount ubuntu partition : `sudo mount /dev/sd* /mnt`

Open Nautilus as root : `sudo dbus-launch nautilus`

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>H</kbd> - then open 'Computer' => `/mnt` folder.
Go to the location of the `.Trash-0` folder and delete it.

**Note** :  `*` = disk / partition (e.g. : `sda1`)
You can use GParted for identification.

Comment: I am trying to move the folder to /mnt n delete it from there. Hope it works that way.

Comment: @Meghraj - I think you missunderstood -  you have to execute  the operation following the steps I described from ubuntu live media !

Comment: I just wanted to try this way once. Actually I have installed it in VMware. While deleting it say, cannot be deleted, read only file system. Its located in root.. .snapshot/.Trash-0

Comment: @Meghraj - so you are talking about a VM install, you should have said this before ! Your problem is not ubuntu related - as it seems you are dealing with a snapshot thing, you only can solve it from within VMware machine management.